# A continuous function also being onto

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there is no continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is onto.

I'm assuming you use the definition of onto and continuous, I just don't know how to use the two together.

Comment: The solutions of the equations $f(x)=1$, $f(x)=2$, $f(x)=3$, ... accumulate somewhere in $[0,1]$. Can the function be continuous at that point?

Comment: HINT: Bounded vs. Unbounded

Comment: Bounded vs. unbounded does nothing. (0,1) is homeomorphism to the real line.

Comment: We aren't discussing $(0, 1)$ here, @Luis...

Comment: Yes I understand that but the fact that [0,1] is bounded tells you nothing about the nonexistance of the function. Really the best way to do it is by the hint below.

Comment: @Luis: A bounded set $A$ cannot have a homeomorphic function mapping $A$ to an unbounded set $B$.

Comment: I just gave you an example. (0,1) is homeomorphic to the real line. Try proving this.

Comment: @DonLarynx It most certainly can. $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$. Take the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(x)+\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I am confusing my definitions! I meant to differentiate between closed and open. So instead, closed (in this case, [0,1]) vs open (the whole metric). @Luis

Comment: Still does not do much for us. Continuous maps do not necessarily take open to open nor closed to closed.

Comment: @DonLarynx You still don't see the big picture. Yes, $\mathbb{R}$ is open. However, $\mathbb{R}$ is also closed as $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{R}$ is the empty set, which is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{R}$ is both closed and open (hence clopin). Sets can be both depending on the set and the topology. They can also be neither! The main idea to show that you can't have a continuous onto function is my hint below.

Comment: @user108675 Really, the hint below is the best way to do it. It is very important that you understand the counterintuitive results in this thread. This is a good problem to show the use of topological invariants.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The interval $[0,1]$ is compact. $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. What were to happen if you had a continuous and onto function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$? What would that imply about $\mathbb{R}$ to create a contradiction?